# Where should my currents go?

Tags: geography, earth-like, ocean, currents

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to place currents in the green area. There doesn't seem to be anywhere for them to come from, and I seem to have backed myself into a corner with the geography of this continent. Any idea what the currents here should look like?

Comment: Your currants should go to Raisans :D

Comment: A note on some of your other currents: the flow in long, skinny basins tends more towards "local eddies" than "long, basin-scouring flows".

Answer (score 9):

Don't get fooled by the scale of the map, there are currents there as in every body of water.

Look at a map of oceanic currents. Do you see any current in the Adriatic sea (the sea between Italy and the Balcans)? You will find no currents there.

[image]

But it doesn't mean there are no currents. You can find plenty of maps showing the currents in the Adriatic sea, if you sort of "zoom in".

[image]

Also in your case, try to look at more fine details of the region, and following the same principles you have used for the large scale circulation, you should be able to determine the circulation in that smaller region.

Don't forget to take into account the boundary conditions where the ocean is met at the eastern border of that region.